# Create generic Func from reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I've specified type in a variable: `Type hiddenType`. I need to create a `Func<T>` delegate where `T` is of type specified in mentioned variable and assign an method:

```
var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(hiddenType);
Func<object> funcImplementation = () => GetInstance(hiddenType);

var myFunc= Delegate.CreateDelegate(funcType , valueGenerator.Method);
```

It doesn't works - because `funcImplementation` is returns `object` instead of desired. At runtime, it will surely be an instance of type specified in `hiddenType`.

`GetInstance` returns `object` and signaure cannot be changed.

Comment: I do not see what you want to achieve. As `GetInstance` returns only `object` as per declaration the `Func<object>` is absolutly okay here.

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP wants `myFunc` to be `Func<HiddenType>`, not `Func<object>`. He tried using `CreateDelegate` for it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this by building an expression tree manually, and inserting a cast to `hiddenType`. This is allowed when you construct an expression tree.

```
var typeConst = Expression.Constant(hiddenType);
MethodInfo getInst = ... // <<== Use reflection here to get GetInstance info
var callGetInst = Expression.Call(getInst, typeConst);
var cast = Expression.Convert(callGetInst, hiddenType);
var del = Expression.Lambda(cast).Compile();
```

**Note:** the above code assumes that `GetInstance` is `static`. If it is not static, change the way you construct `callGetInst` to pass the object on which the method is invoked.

Comment: However the resulting delegate is not strongly typed which I assume the OP actually wanted.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This delegate will be strongly typed, in the sense that its type will be compatible with `typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(hiddenType)`. Of course it would not be a statically typed delegate (which is not possible, because the type is hidden).

Comment: Thanks! I though for a while that `Expression` could do the thing, but I didn't know how to eat that piece of cake.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Type, you could consider using a generic wrapper, if it's not possible for you to change the GetInstance signature:

```
private Func<THidden> GetTypedInstance<THidden>()
{
    return () => (THidden)GetInstance(typeof(THidden));
}
```

Then you can just call it with

```
GetTypedInstance<SomeClass>();
```

instead of

```
GetInstance(typeof(SomeClass));
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `hiddenType` is only known at runtime thus statically binding to a generic wrapper won´t work.