# How to instantiate a Lazy<Square> using runtime type info, and a function that only returns Shape?

Tags: c#

I want to create a `Lazy<>` with runtime information about the contained type, but I'm not sure how to create the required `Func<>` initializer. I feel the answer is somewhere in `Delegate.CreateDelegate`, but I couldn't see how to make that work. The below illustrates what I want to do:

```
class ShapeTools {
    abstract class Shape {}
    class Square : Shape {}

    Lazy<Square> aLazyShape;

    ShapeTools() {
        setup(GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.Name == "aLazyShape").First());
    }

    // returns a shape matching the provided type (unimplemented)
    Shape GetShape(Type shapeType) { return null; }

    void setup (FieldInfo field) { // aLazyShape
        var funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType); // = typeof(Func<Square>)
        var shapeType = funcType.GetGenericArguments().First(); // = typeof(Square)
        // var myFunc = Activator.CreateInstance(funcType, () => { return GetShape(shapeType); }) // doesn't compile - type doesn't match

        var lazy = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType, myFunc); // This takes a Func<Square>
        field.SetValue(this, lazy);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you're looking for by using System.Linq.Expressions.  *Why* you want to do it this way is another thing.  =)

See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916280/create-generic-func-from-reflection) for where the key parts about using `Expression` came from.

Note that your code for creating `var funcType` was not returning `typeof(Func<Square>)`, but instead `typeof(Func<Lazy<Square>>)`; I fixed that.  Most things were made `public` for convenience when compiling. You could change the access to GetShape if you want to update BindingFlags in the call to GetMethod, for example.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ShapeTools st = new ShapeTools();
            ShapeTools.Square s = st.aLazyShape.Value;
            // s will be whatever ShapeTools.GetShape returns
        }

        public class ShapeTools
        {
            public abstract class Shape { }
            public class Square : Shape { }

            public Lazy<Square> aLazyShape;

            public ShapeTools()
            {
                setup(GetType().GetFields().Where(f => f.Name == "aLazyShape").First());
            }

            // returns a shape matching the provided type (unimplemented, just an example)
            public static object GetShape(Type shapeType) { return new Square(); }

            void setup(FieldInfo field)
            { // only handles 'aLazyShape' right now
                Type funcType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType.GenericTypeArguments[0]); // = typeof(Func<Square>)
                Type shapeType = funcType.GetGenericArguments().First(); // = typeof(Square)

                // get MethodInfo for the static method in this class that returns the right shape
                MethodInfo getInstanceOfType = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(GetShape));

                // build the Func dynamically
                var typeConst = Expression.Constant(shapeType); // get the shapeType as an Expression
                var callGetInstance = Expression.Call(getInstanceOfType, typeConst); // invoke our (static) method to get the instance of shape
                var cast = Expression.Convert(callGetInstance, shapeType); // cast the return of our method (which is object) to the right type
                var toLambda = Expression.Lambda(cast); // wrap everything in a Lambda to return our instance
                var finalFunc = toLambda.Compile(); // compile to the final Func

                var lazy = Activator.CreateInstance(field.FieldType, finalFunc); // now create the Lazy<T>, where T is Square
                field.SetValue(this, lazy);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, notice that `GetShape` was made static.  This was for convenience when using Expressions - if you want, you can pass in an instance of ShapeTools to the Expressions code instead.

And as written, `ShapeTools.setup` is just an example of how this can work.  I assume you'd want to clean it up to handle other field types than just `Lazy<Shape>`.

Comment: Ah thanks I'll give this a shot - I did read up on Expressions a bit, but thought they were a tool for a different sort of problem. Will report back :)

Comment: Even if Expressions were created with a different problem in mind (I can't speak much to minds of the creators), like the rest of System.Linq, the concept can be applied to a number of use cases.

Comment: Separately, as @Blindy points out in their answer, there could be a performance hit for doing it this way.  I'm just pointing out it's possible - in effect, finishing the first option from @Blindy.  If I were to choose one of their three options, I'd go with #3 or some other refactor, to avoid both Reflection and `dynamic` unless it's truly necessary.  But we'd need much more context on your problem to decide on that.

Comment: Got it working! :D The actual use case: given ample free time lately, I'm messing around with Unity. I want to create component accessors as fields like `var _collider = new Lazy<Collider2D>(() => { return this.GetComponent<Collider2D>(); }`, and then a getter helper property which isn't important. But the above won't work because I can't access `this` in the capture for the lambda used to initialize the `Lazy<>`. Instead, I tag it with an attribute, and in a shared base class do the above assignment, keeping my client logic as clean as possible.

Answer (score -1):

> `// var myFunc = Activator.CreateInstance(funcType, () => { return GetShape(shapeType); }) // doesn't compile - type doesn't match`

C# is a statically typed language, and as such every type has to be fully known at compile time. As you discovered, while you can ask the runtime to create you any type you build the definition for (with a `Type` object), the return type has to be fully known -- the function you call returns `object` for that very reason.

You have a few options here:

1. Stay on the object level, and use further reflection calls to consume your newly created object. Large performance hit, of course.
2. Go `dynamic`, which creates a compiler site to translate any calls through it. It also spreads like a plague, anything that uses `dynamic` returns `dynamic`, so until you get something you know the type of you'll be using this kind of calls. Amortized moderate performance hit, very high performance hit during the first JIT compilation.
3. Use interfaces. You have a base class already, if you define it smart enough, that should be all you need to use your object. That `myfunc` function would be of type `Func<Shape>` in that case, and it obviously can only access the `Shape` portion of your object, though you're free to try casting using `is`/`as` as needed, usually in `if`s.  Very low performance hit, but you need to design your type smart (which you should be doing anyway).

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, the way you create that `Func` object is wrong, you don't ask the activator to create it, you assign it to a piece of code by its name (or header, in the case of lambda functions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you have a code example on how to  to do #1? With only changing `setup()`

Comment: Sure, if I read this function correctly, it all boils down to `field.SetValue(this, () => (object)GetShape(typeof(Square)));` though of course you need to update the field you're setting the value for to have the proper type (`Func<object>`).

Comment: It's more complicated as the field is a lazy, and it's constructor requires a `Func<Square>`, not a `Func<object>` or even `Fun<Shape>`

Comment: Regardless of how complicated you made it, I told you what a statically typed language like C# can do. You might be better off using something like Python if you don't know how to structure your code in proper statically typed fashion.